# $.el is undefined in backbone-ui.js when attempting to render table

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

i am getting a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'table' of undefined" when attempting to render a backbone ui table. Im simply trying to render the example table from the website. I have tried searching around for the setting of the el variable but nothing seems to be working. Any help greatly appreciated. The example code is as below. A simple collection that i am trying to display in the backbone ui table view. JS error occurs in render method inside backbone-ui.js

```
window.regions = new Backbone.Collection([{
    name: 'Americas',
    notes: 'Bright'
}, {
    name: 'Africa',
    notes: 'Fruity'
}]);

var table = new Backbone.UI.TableView({
    el: $('#table_container'),
    sortable: true,
    model: regions,
    columns: [{
        title: 'Name',
        content: 'name'
    }, {
        title: 'Notes',
        content: 'notes'
    }]
}).render();
```

Comment: i have it all wrapped in $(document).ready(function() {})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could not get it going so i changed to using datatables js

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Backbone UI source, TableView doesn't accept el as an option. That's probably why you get an error on render. Try removing it. You should try wrapping it in the container or appending it to the DOM (depending on if #table_container already exists or not) post render.

```
table.appendTo('#table_container);
```

or

```
table.wrap('<div id="table_container"></div>').appendTo(~wherever~);
```